# How to do Java lambda sum on Double not Integer?

Tags: java, lambda

I have this obscene block of java lambda code that works (it sums a collection of integers, Netbeans IDE wrote it for me....)

```
Integer  thesum = times.values().stream().filter((val) -> (val != null)).reduce(thesum, Integer::sum);
```

Now the "times" Map changed to a `Map<String,Double>`not a `Map<String,Integer>` like above,
However, simply changing the `Integer::sum` to `Double::sum` doesn't work

```
   Double  thesum = times.values().stream().filter((val) -> (val != null)).reduce(thesum, Double::sum);//does not work
```

Why is it different with doubles vs integers?

TBH I actually don't care, because this works and IMO is more understandable anyway

```
 for(double d : times.values()){
          thesum+=d;
 }
```

But I thought those who enjoy the construction of lambda syntax as a form of human happiness and personal gratification might want to see an answer to this, because it annoyed me almost as much as the general syntax construct itself.

Thanks

Comment: `double thesum = times.values().stream().filter(x -> x != null).mapToDouble(Double::valueOf).sum();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the variable 'thesum' not being initialised before use; The code looks fine and compiles & runs as expected in eclipse.

I've added an example below, formatted for clarity

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String,Double> times = new HashMap<>();
    times.put("1", 1.0);
    times.put("2", 2.0);
    times.put("null", null);
    times.put("3", 3.0);
    times.put("4", 4.0);

    Double thesum = 0.0;
    thesum = times.values().stream()
        .filter((val) -> (val != null))
        .reduce(thesum, Double::sum);

    System.out.println(thesum); // 10.0
}
```

Comment: Thank you! apparently my brain is even more annoying than lambda syntax, because I must have been doing something else silly, because now it works. I wonder if I had forgotten to change the variable to a Double.... oh the humanity. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The use of `reduce` here seems awkward. The Stream API includes a `DoubleStream` which can sum the values directly:

```
Double sum = times.values().stream().mapToDouble(n -> n).sum();
```

The `mapToDouble` is not particularly elegant but it's the easiest way I know to map from a `Stream<Double>` to a `DoubleStream`.

Also note that your `for` loop is not strictly equivalent to the stream version as it does not cope with `null` values.